# Parallel outgoing calls: Freeswitch

Tags: twilio, voip, freeswitch

Can I make multiple outgoing calls to different numbers at the same time in Freeswitch?

I'm new to freeswitch and am trying to understand how it all works.
Trying to achieve twilio like functionality whereby I can dial out to multiple numbers at once using the same phone number.

Comment: `,` is for parallel/hunt all calling and `|` is for serial/one by one  calling. 
`:_:` `Enterprise originate`is same like Parallel used if you want to set diff variables in case if you want to try sip and pstn hunting in parallel manner.
https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Freeswitch_IVR_Originate

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can call several endpoints simultaneously by separating destinations with commas like this:

```
<action application="bridge" data="sofia/internal/100%${sip_profile},sofia/internal/101%${sip_profile}"/>
```

More details you can find here:

https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_dptools%3A+bridge

Comment: it says the first one to answer wins. So does that mean only one actual call can happen at a time?

Comment: no it means that first one which answers the call will be connected, but all other destinations will get cancel.

Comment: is there any solution that lets you do that without the other destinations being canceled?